# Changing a scheduled task from cmd

Tags: cmd, scheduled-tasks

```
SchTasks /Change /TN "cs2kconnect" /ST 06:00
```

I am getting Error the Parameter is Incorrect

The taskname is correct as I copied it directly, and when I put in a bad time it says /ST is Invalid.

I have managed to edit it other tasks using the same process, just this one does not want to change have tested this on multiple machines.

Any ideas?

This is running under windows 7

Comment: wrong qoutes. `SchTasks /Change /TN "My Task" /ST 14:00`. (`"`, not `”`)

Comment: @stephan Even with correct quotations it still not working, the actual task name I am using is all one word so I technically don't even need quotes

Comment: Searching with a www search engine for `schtasks change "parameter is incorrect"` returns lots of web pages on Stack Overflow, Super User, Microsoft and other websites. The error message is very poor as it does not contain the real reason why modification of the task failed. For example it could be that the task `cs2kconnect` is created with credentials (user account and password) different to user account and password used on running the command. Therefore change access is denied, but the error message is nevertheless `The parameter is incorrect`. Look on existing answers to find out reason.

Comment: @Mofi Yes I have searched and found similar but I did not find the answer specifying the username and password or running the task locally also does not work

Answer (score 2):

*Though the question is very old but my answer below could be helpful to anybody still searching.*

If you have made sure the name of the task and the parameter values are all correct and still face this error, then it is not because of the command you are running but because of the setup of the task.

You will face this error in 2 cases, first is when you create a Scheduled Task from the GUI and add a Trigger and not change the default Start Time. Second is when you add an Expire date and not change the default date that is set.
[Task Scheduler - Trigger setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5NW1.png)

The reason we get this error is becuase when you setup a trigger and not change its Start time or Expire time, the task scheduler creates it with milliseconds included, you can see that when you export the task to an XML. You will find that after you make any change to the start time and expire time (if it exists) and then export the to XML the milliseconds part is gone. 
[Task Scheduler - XML Export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIScR.png)

To me it seems that when we run the "schtasks /change" command it validates the existing start time and expire time format before applying any change and it fails with this error which is definitely not very descriptive or accurate.

So, the solution is just make a small change to the times (you can change it back to original value) and then run the same command and it should work fine.

This error occurs only in Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2 or earlier versions of OS.

The reason for this error is rather strange and may be is a bug in Windows which Microsoft fixed in later OS versions or in an Update which I could not find.